# ios scanning different device by counting bits

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, scanning

I am working on BLE scanning modules for scanning devices if bit 0x00 is shown up for 10 times  or more. When more than one identical device are scanned,  the console shows alternate 0x00 , 0x01 in NSLog . Since I use one integer counter to count the presence of 0x00 bits, it is often  override-ed . Would you please tell me the way to implement the key/value data structure to save the UUID and the count for storing scannedPeripheral ?

The below is my working

```
  for(NSUInteger  i = 0 ; i < [ _ble.scannedPeripheral count ] ; i ++){
            DevicePeriperal *device;
            NSString *uuid = [_ble.scannedPeripheralKey objectAtIndex:i];
            if (uuid)
            {
                device = [_ble.scannedPeripheral objectForKey:uuid];
                if([self isEmptyArrayOrNil:[_dbMan getDeviceRecord:device.uuid ] ]){

                    NSLog(@"pair bit %@ ," ,  device.pairBit );
                    const unsigned char ssss[1] = {0x00};
                    NSData* pairBi =  [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)ssss length:(sizeof(unsigned char) * 1)];
                    const unsigned char ssLow[1] = {0x01};
                    NSData* pairX =  [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)ssLow length:(sizeof(unsigned char) * 1)];

                    if ([device.pairBit  isEqualToData:pairBi ]){

                        pCount++;
                        if(pCount > 9){
                            NSLog(@"pair bit paired " );
                            NSLog (@"device = %@", device.uuid);                                                           
                        }
                    }else if([device.pairBit  isEqualToData:pairX ]){                            
                        NSLog(@"pair bit not matched " );
                        pCount=0;                            
                    }
                }else{
                    // others
                    NSLog(@"pair bit paired before" );
                    NSLog (@"device = %@", device.uuid);
                }
        }
```

Comment: Are you saying that `pCount` gets 'confused' if there is more than one peripheral?  If so then you need to store a `pCount` per peripheral - I suggest an `NSNumber` stored in an `NSMutableDictionary` keyed by `UUID`

Comment: Danke，I use NSdictonary